# d3 year slider displays area in between steps

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to create a step slider in d3 (v5) with the years 2000 through 2021. (Using plugin d3-simple-slider)

```
    const slider = 
    sliderBottom()
    .min(new Date(2000, 1, 1))
    .max(new Date(2020, 1, 1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y'))
    .tickValues(ar)
    .default(new Date(2000, 10, 3))
    .width(rectWidth - margin.right - 65)
    .height(75)
    .on("onchange", (value) => {
      year = d3.timeFormat('%Y')(value);
    })
```

```
  const g = d3
    .select("#slider")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', rectWidth - margin.right - 65)
    .attr('height', 75)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
```

The slider that is displayed however seems to enable the area in between the "steps" and the year also seems to move along.

1. Is there a way to have only the exact points at the steps enabled?
2. How to make the slider responsive ?

Thanks in advance!

[image: pic]

Comment: https://d3-simple-slider.mulberryhousesoftware.com/?path=/story/functionality-basic-functionality--step

Comment: According to their documentation, add: `.step(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)` (number of milliseconds in a year)

Comment: already tried, still not fixed

Comment: I need to show the tick values as [2000, 2002, 2004, and so on..], that is the case here

Comment: So set step to `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2`, and ensure your first year is even

Comment: If we add 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2 to steps, then how can a user select an odd year ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky ?

Comment: OK, I suppose I did not understand you correctly. You want to select both even and od years, but display ticks for the even years only. Rihgt?

Comment: Yes exactly @MichaelRovinsky

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your data to have the even years only and set as `tickValues` :

```js
const tickData = data.reduce((a, v, i) => i % 2 === 0 ? [...a, v] : a, []);

const slider = sliderBottom()
  .min(min(data))
  .max(max(data))
  .step(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
  .tickFormat(timeFormat('%Y'))
  .tickValues(tickData)
  . . .
```

Comment: Still not fixed, this is the same thing that i am passing in tickValues, where ar is even years filtered